# No MathJax line wrapping in Firefox

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Example:

[image]

Chrome, for comparison:

[image]

Happens on Windows 10, both browsers are up to date.
Should I use the [bug](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/bug) tag?
Does anybody else encounter this? Can it be something on my side?

After the question in a comment by Martin Sleziak: actually I cannot access the MathJax menu anywhere on Firefox.

Additional info:

When I edit that question and replace the `$$` with `\begin{multline*}` .. `\end{multline*}` the wrapping renders correctly.

In Firefox under [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) inside the same system it renders correctly, and I can access the MathJax menu too.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you switch the math renderer? (See also: [How do I change Math Renderer for MathJax?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30859))

Comment: @MartinSleziak Good question! I cannot access the MathJax menu anywhere on Firefox!

Comment: That's interesting - here's is a screenshot showing also what I get in FF (including the MathJax menu): https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL04K.png To save work for the user who want to try this on the same post, I will add a link: [Integral representation of product of two Whittaker functions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/373947).

Comment: Did you try to force reload the page to override cache (Ctrl+Shift+R or Ctrl+F5)?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Tried now, rendered MathJax momentarily turns into TeX code and then returns to the same

Comment: Are you really sure you cannot access the MathJax menu? It can be somewhat difficult to get it right at times. You need to place cursor over a rendered element of the MathJax expression (ideally, something with a large area, such as one of the $W$’s in the displayed equation); in most (but not all) modes, a correct place is visually indicated by the pointer cursor changing to a text cursor. Then you right click.

Comment: FWIW, for me (Firefox 89 on Linux) the line breaks display correctly with most Math Renderer settings (including the default “HTML-CSS”), with the exception of “Preview HTML” and “MathML”, which make it look similar to your screenshot.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I tried at several different expressions of various sizes. When I hover over it, occasionally the cursor changes from an arrow to a vertical line, but in any case when I right click I just get the default Firefox menu that appears upon the right click anywhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by helpful comments and answer, I found the reason.
I had the [Native MathML](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/native-mathml/) Firefox add-on installed, I switched it off and everything renders correctly now, also I can access the MathJax menu.

In fact this seems to be [a bug in that add-on](https://github.com/fred-wang/webextension-native-mathml/issues/14) known from March 2020.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be about inability of firefox@windows to handle explicit `\\` in displayed maths - you can look at the source of the [Integral representation of product of two Whittaker functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/373947/integral-representation-of-product-of-two-whittaker-functions) question you are talking about.

I also see that it works just fine in firefox@linux (Firefox version 87.0).

(It's not some kind of automatic wrapping broken, it's more basic)

---

Edit: it was pointed out that it's invalid LaTeX in that equation, so this can be closed.

Comment: Not surprising, given that Windows treats `\\` differently, contributing to driving developers to insanity quite a lot :-)

Comment: Your answer gave me an idea. I edited that question and replaced the `$$` with `\begin{multline*}` `\end{multline*}` (without touching the `\\ `). It renders correctly in the preview.

Comment: Besides, it is still not clear why I cannot access the MathJax menu

Comment: In my Firefox I can do this --- switch to Linux :P

Comment: Well I've got WSL. Maybe one day I'll migrate without even noticing it :)

Comment: I suggest WLS 2, not 1 - just in case.

Comment: Probably I should have explicitly mentioned that [screenshot I posted above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL04K.png) was from Firefox under Windows.

Comment: Oh dear, I didn’t notice that there were `\\ ` inside `$$...$$` without any proper environment. This is basically invalid syntax, and it is not supposed to work. (In actual LaTeX, it *doesn’t* produce a line break.) You seem not to have submitted the edit, so I will.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek It is clear that this is not correct in LaTeX. Whether or not this is suppose to work in MathJax is a separated question. There are a few related comments and links [in the MathJax chatrom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13752/conversation/using-for-linebreaks).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I see, I wasn’t aware of that. Usually, MathJax strives to be compatible to LaTeX, so this is an odd exception.